# Jmeter ADFS authentication

Tags: jmeter

I am looking for a solution for the below problem statement:

1. Authentication is done through `ADFS`.
2. I recorded a script via `jmeter/blazemeter/badboy`, but observed that `RequestSecurityTokenResponse` is never returned in response for any request.
3. Observed that the `RequestSecurityTokenResponse` is directly sent over a URL via reply by `ADFS`.

Due to above situation I am not able to extract the `RequestSecurityTokenResponse` and hence I'm not able to parameterize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler to record the application and search by text "RequestSecurityTokenResponse " in Fiddler then you will get the request in which response you will get it.
This is an xml which you need to capture from the response of https://qfs.XXXX.com/adfs/ls/?prompt=login&client-request-XXXXXXXX request then you need to replace '<' by '<' and '&quot' by '"' and pass it whole xml to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf request .